# BigCommerce Stencil YAML showing on live template

Tags: handlebars.js, yaml, bigcommerce

I installed a fresh Cornerstone theme locally.  I made no edits to this theme, I then bundled that and uploaded to the store.  The issue is that the YAML is showing and theme.css file is not loading.
http://redandwhitestenciltest2.mybigcommerce.com/?ctk=PRDU0TFJXWZG451IOS7F35MC7

Any ideas or help?

Comment: What OS are you running?

Comment: Windows 10, thank you for the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a symptom of Windows specific bundling issues which we are testing and awaiting merge. It can be identified internally as MERC-683 if you need to contact BigCommerce for any reason.

You can send it to a non-windows environment to bundle or await the merge.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help Alyss!

Comment: Happy to help, Dusten :)